# "Calculated on every Tick" is true, but varip only updates at the bar close

Tags: pine-script

My attempt is to check if the price target is reached, the "varip target_triggered" turns true.

I turn the "Calculated on every Tick" true since I want the varip to be updated real time, but the "varip target_triggered"  only update to true when the bar close.

How can I fix this ? Here is the code.

```
varip bool target_triggered = na

if trade_start_condition 
    target_triggered==false

if target_triggered==false and ta.cross(close,price_target)
    alert("Target Hit !!")
    sl_alert_triggered := true
```

Sincerely Thanks